# glGenBuffers is null in GLEW?

Tags: c, opengl, sdl-2, glew

I wrote a simple program using OpenGL, SDL 2, and GLEW. It works properly on Linux, under Wine, and on one Windows 7 system I ran it on. However, on another Windows system, it is crashing as soon as it gets to glGenBuffers, even though it says OpenGL 2.1 is available. Here is the code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

SDL_Window *window;
SDL_GLContext context;

GLuint vbo;

void Init() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_GL_LoadLibrary(NULL);
    int min, max;
    SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION,&max);
    SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION,&min);
    printf("Default OpenGL version %d.%d\n",max,min);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION,2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION,1);
    SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION,&max);
    SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION,&min);
    printf("OpenGL version %d.%d\n",max,min);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL,1);
    window=SDL_CreateWindow("", 0, 0, 500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    glewExperimental=1;
    GLenum err=glewInit();
    if(GLEW_OK!=err)
    {
        printf("Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        return(1);
    }

    if(window==NULL) {
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return(1);
    }
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    float data[][2] = {{50,50},{100,50},{75,100}};
    glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void Render() {
    glViewport(0,0, (GLsizei) 500, (GLsizei) 500);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0f, (GLdouble) 500, 0.0f, (GLdouble) 500);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 2*sizeof(float), 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Init();
    Render();
    SDL_Delay(2000);
    glDeleteBuffers(1,&vbo);
    return(0);
}
```

Here is some more information I have added since initially posting this question:

- Using %p to print the address of glBindBuffer, it is 0.
- Both (GLEW_ARB_vertex_buffer_object == GL_TRUE) and (GLEW_ARB_vertex_array_object == GL_TRUE) return 0.
- glGetString(GL_RENDERER) returns "GDI Generic".
- I have also tried setting the depth size to 16, but that still doesn't work.
- The graphics card is an Nvidia 750 TI.

Comment: What if you get rid of the glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); line?

Comment: It still crashes. Neither example on this page works (https://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples), and the second example does not use glEnableClientState at all. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I have since updated the question with more information.

Comment: Are you sure that everything is ok with your context? May be smth like this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38907885/4298340